# Reload environment variables without relogin to desktop

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, environment-variables

I've found multiple ways to update environment variables to an Ubuntu system with a desktop environment, some common answers are:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/etc/profile` and `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`
- `$HOME/.profile`
- `$HOME/.pam_environment`

And well many also say `$HOME/.bashrc` which only applies to bash and so is really not correct.

It does not seem to be possible to update the environment via any of these means in a running system. If I open a new terminal tab, a new terminal window, close the terminal and reopen the entire application, or launch a completely different application, at no point does any of them seem to re-evaluate any of these files

Since I need to update the environment on a regular basis for development tools etc., and have multiple long running tasks (stuff that takes days or weeks to complete) that I don't want to terminate, this is not particularly convenient.

How do I get a *running desktop environment* to reload and apply updates to environment variables, so that I don't have to close everything I'm doing to get newly launched software (e.g. IDEs, Git GUI clients, etc.) to see the updated environment?

If it matters, I'm using XFCE4 for the desktop environment.

Comment: I've been desperate enough to try writing to `/proc/$PID/environ` but that gives me a `write error: Invalid argument` 

Comment: For "development tools" I'd typically export whatever environment variables I want in a shell and then start the tool from that shell. Or run them all in their own containers, so I can modify and restart the containers as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `source` command to re-read the file in question, for example

```
source $HOME/.profile
```

It can be abbriavated to a dot like

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

But if you want to set some environment variables to use in application, it might be more feasable just to set them in a shell session and start the application from there, as muru mentioned in a comment. This would be something like

```
export LANG=fr_FR
/some/path/to/an/executable
```

You could also set an environment variable for one specific command

```
LANG=fr_FR /some/path/to/an/executable
```

If you use something like the above on a regular basis, you could write a short script that does the task, something like

```
#!/bin/bash
export LANG=fr_FR
/some/path/to/an/executable
```

Put the script somewhere in your $PATH, let's say `/usr/local/bin` with a name like for example `start_important_application`, and then you can use this command to start your app.

It *may* be possible to use something like `LANG=fr_FR some_command` in the `Exec` key of a custom starter file (those files that end with `.desktop`), but I haven't tested that.

Comment: I'm talking about desktop applications, not shell scripts. I want newly launched desktop applications to have the new environment without me requiring to reboot or start them from some tweaked shell.

Comment: @JanneEnberg Desktop environments basically take whatever starter files they find in specific directories and build their menus (or whatever the metaphor used is) from that. So you could try to create a custom starter like I described. Or you could write a short script that sets the environment variables and starts the app, and have a custom starter call that script. I'm not familiar enough with XFCE to tell you where it looks for starter files, but `$HOME/.local/share/applications` (which at least GNOME uses) might be a good first try.